# How to plot mark on every nth point?

Tags: pgfplots

I have a long CSV data file:

```
x,y1,y2...
1,v1,v1...
2,v2,v2...
....
```

I use `pgfplots` to plot all the lines. I also want to add mark shapes. But the problem is that the data is too dense, and I have a limited space, so the marks  stick together.

I tried:

```
 \addplot[blue, thin, mark=square, each nth point=20] table ...
```

But it also skipped the data points.

I want to have a smooth line, but only a few marks. How can I do that?

Comment: You need `mark repeat` key sya `mark repeat=10` will repeat marks once in ten.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use `mark repeat` key to repeat marks at frequent intervals. `mark phase` will tell at which point the marks should start. For example,

```
make repeat = r,
mark phase = p
```

will put the mark  first at `p`th point and then at `p+r` th and then `p+2r`th point etc. An example from the manual

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title=Without \texttt{mark repeat}]
\addplot+[scatter,samples=100] {sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title= With \texttt{mark repeat=5,mark phase=7}]
\addplot+[scatter,samples=100,
mark repeat=5,mark phase=7]
{sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]